# Zeusminer not being recognized with BFGminer

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, asic, bfgminer

I'm trying to run `bfgminer` on a Raspberry Pi but the `zeusminer` is not being recognized. When I run the command:

```
sudo bfgminer-5.1.0/bfgminer -S zeusminer:all -d? -D
```

I get:

```
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] setrlimit: Soft fd limit not being changed from 1024 (FD_SETSIZE=1024; hard limit=4096)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] Started bfgminer 5.1.0
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:007 (path=(null), vid=1c4f, pid=0002, manuf=SIGMACHIP, prod=USB Keyboard, serial=(null))
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:006 (path=(null), vid=0403, pid=6001, manuf=FTDI, prod=FT232R USB UART, serial=AH02YA6E)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:005 (path=(null), vid=0bda, pid=8176, manuf=Realtek, prod=802.11n WLAN Adapter, serial=00e04c000001)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:004 (path=(null), vid=1a40, pid=0201, manuf=(null), prod=USB 2.0 Hub [MTT], serial=(null))
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:003 (path=(null), vid=0424, pid=ec00, manuf=(null), prod=(null), serial=(null))
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:001 (path=(null*), vid=1d6b, pid=0002, manuf=Linux 3.18.11-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd, prod=DWC OTG Controller, serial=bcm2708_usb)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found usb device at usb:001:002 (path=(null), vid=0424, pid=9514, manuf=(null), prod=(null), serial=(null))
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found ft232r device at usb:001:006 (path=(null), vid=0403, pid=6001, manuf=FTDI, prod=FT232R USB UART, serial=AH02YA6E)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] lowlevel_scan: Found vcom device at dev_t:00bc000000000000 (path=/dev/ttyUSB0, vid=0000, pid=0000, manuf=FTDI, prod=FT232R USB UART, serial=AH02YA6E)
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] Devices detected:
 [2015-05-31 19:47:42] Timers: Using clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)
 0 devices listed
```

Here is my command to try and get bfgminer to run:

```
sudo bfgminer-5.1.0/bfgminer --scrypt -o <pool> -u <user>.<worker> -p <password> -S zeusminer:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

I have tried running the `-S` flag with `zeusminer:all`, `zeusminer:auto`, and `zeusminer:/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm running BFGminer 5.4.0 on a pi with two Zeusminers. Here is an example of my command that I run:

`--scrypt -o stratum+tcp://pool:port -u username -p password -S zeusminer:/dev/ttyUSB0 --set zeusminer:clock=328 --set zeusminer:chips=6 -S zeusminer:/dev/ttyUSB1 --set zeusminer:clock=328 --set zeusminer:chips=6`